# How to set up Laravel 5 with Twig and translations?

Tags: internationalization, laravel-5, twig, translation

I want to have project with:

- Laravel 5
- Twig template engine
- trans tag in Twig, which works with standard Laravel translations (based on php arrays)

Here is my composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
    "rcrowe/TwigBridge": "~0.8.1"
}
```

app.php:

```
'providers' => [
    // ...
    TwigBridge\ServiceProvider::class,
    // ...
]

'aliases' => [
    'Twig'      => TwigBridge\Facade\Twig::class,
],
```

Here is my controller:

```
class Page extends Controller
{
    public function home()
    {
        $name = 'Guest';
        return Twig::render('twig.twig', compact('name'));
    }
}
```

But I have this error:

```
ReflectionException in Container.php line 736:
Class view does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used the TwigBridge multiple times in my projects without getting that error, but instead of `Twig::render` you can still use the standard Laravel `View::make` functionality. https://github.com/rcrowe/TwigBridge#usage

My steps for installation:

1. Require in composer
2. Add the service provider `'TwigBridge\ServiceProvider',`
3. Add the facase `'Twig' => 'TwigBridge\Facade\Twig',`
4. Use the `View::make` or `view('view', $params)`

The default translator class of Laravel is already included in the TwigBridge so you can just use `{{ trans('website.key') }}` if i remember correctly
https://github.com/rcrowe/TwigBridge#functionsfiltersvariables

Comment: I tried also your way to write app.php, but it throws the same error. Can you check if it works for you? Maybe smth is broken in Laravel or TwigBridge? Now I have error: ReflectionException in Container.php line 736: Class view does not exist

Comment: @razbakov What did you try to write in your app.php?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as yours, try to add provider and aliases in the end of variables (after View)